# Storing Serialized Information In SQL Server using F#

Tags: sql-server, serialization, f#

I am currently working on a project in F# that takes in data from Excel spreadsheets, determines if it is compatible with an existing table in SQL Server, and then adds the relevant rows to the existing table.

Some of the data I am working with is more specific than the types provided by T-SQL. That is, T-SQL has a type "date", but I need to distinguish between sets of dates that are at the beginning of each month or the end of each month. This same logic applies to many other types as well. If I have types:

```
Date(Beginning)
Date(End)
```

they will both be converted to the T-SQL type "date" before being added to the table, therefore erasing some of the more specific information.

In order to solve this problem, I am keeping a log of the serialized types in F#, along with which column number in the SQL Server table they apply to. My question is: is there any way to store this log somewhere internally in SQL Server so that I can access it and compare the serialized types of the incoming data to the serialized types of the data that already exists in the table before making new inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping metadata outside of the DB and maintaining them manually makes your DB "expensive" to manage plus increases the risk of errors that you might not even detect until something bad happens.

If you have control over the table schema, there are at least a couple of simple options. For example, you can add a column that stores the type info. For something simple with just a couple of possible values as you described, just add a new column to store the actual type value. Update the F# code to de-serialize the source into separate DATE and type (BEGINNING/END) values which are then inserted  to the table. Simple, easy to maintain and easily consumed.

You could also create a user defined type for each date subtype but that can be confusing to another DBA/dev plus makes it more complicated when retrieving data from your application. This is generally not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that if you want to.